# '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: pygame

I'm trying to make my character follow my mouse position(I dont want him to instantly teleport I only need him to go to my mouse direction) so I made this script and I get the error:

> `'>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'.`

```py
mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        Running = False

mpos = (mx, my)
X = int(playerX)
Y = int(playerY)

if mpos >= Y: 
    playerY -= vel

    
if mpos <= Y:
    playerY += vel

if mpos <= X:
    playerX -= vel

if mpos >= X:
    playerX += vel
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `mpos` is a tuple. How you do you expect `<` to work on multiple values?

Comment: I fixed it like you said but the movement is a bit laggy and unrealistic, but it does follow my mouse
'''
if mpos[1] >= Y: 
        playerY += vel

    
    if mpos[1] <= Y:
        playerY -= vel

        
    if mpos[0] <= X:
        playerX -= vel

    if mpos[0] >= X:
        playerX += vel
'''

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just have a typo in your script. Your are comparing `Y` and `X` to (the tuple) `mpos`, but you actually want to compare it to `mx` and `my`, respectively.